# What are any side-effects of declaring something as size_t that I should be aware of?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Making class for work with stack (code is not mine)

I have code like this:

```
class stack {
private:
    int size;
    int* data;
    // what next line mean?
    size_t ptr;
    public:


stack(int valid_stack_size) {
    this->size = valid_stack_size;
    this->ptr = 0;
    this->data = new int[valid_stack_size];
}

void push(int value) {
    if (this->ptr >= (size_t)this->size)
        cout << "Stack is full" << endl;
    this->data[this->ptr++] = value;

}

int pop() {
    if (this->ptr == 0)
        cout << "Stack is empty" << endl;

    return this->data[--this->ptr];

}



};
```

what does size_t ptr mean? size_t takes ptr value? or?

Comment: `size_t ptr;` does essentially the same thing as `int size;`

Comment: All those `this->`s are noise. None of them is needed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is covered by every basic c++ beginners book or tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

`size_t` is a type - defined in header file `cstddef` as a type which can hold the maximum size of the object. On modern systems, it's usually equal with the size of the pointer, and this is often 64 bit (8 bytes). However, this is not required by the standard.

As a result, this line declares the variable `ptr` of type `size_t`, which is confusing - `ptr` as a name suggest the variable type should be a pointer.

On a side note, this code exhibits undefined behavior - when popping on empty stack or pushing into full one.

Answer (score 2):

`size_t` is implementation defined unsigned integer type.

For example, `size_t` can be defined the following way

```
typedef unsigned long size_t;
```

that is according to this definition `size_t` is an alias for the type `unsigned long`.

From the C Standard (7.19 Common definitions `<stddef.h>`)

> **size_t** 
>   which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator;

Or in the C++ Standard there is written (18.2 Types)

> 6 The type size_t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type
>   that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.

In C++ the definition of `size_t` (declared in header `<cstddef>`) is also placed in the namespace `std`. So you can also write

```
std::size_t ptr;
```

Thus this line of the code

```
size_t ptr;
```

means a declaration of identifier `ptr` that determinates the current position in the stack as having type `size_t` that in turn is more commonly defined as `unsigned long int`.

As for the code you showed then the name `ptr` is not very good for a scalar  integer object. It would be better to name it for example like `pos` (abbreviation of the word "position")